# Extracting data from website using VBA

Tags: html, ms-access, vba

I want to extract the projectstatus of a project which I can find on a website. See below for an example how the  html is parsed. I want to extract the text **Start** which is the text between td and /td. See below the html my code.

```
 <div id="ProjectStatus">
 <tr>
 <th>
 <span id="ProjectStatus_Label1" title="De status van het project">Projectstatus</span>
 </th>
 <td>Start</td>
 </tr>
```

Below you'll find the code that I have at this moment. This code only gives me the string "Projectstatus", which is not what I want. How can I extract the word "Start"?

```
Private Sub btnClick()

Dim ieApp As InternetExplorer
Set ieApp = New InternetExplorer
Set ieApp = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

With ieApp
 .Navigate "url"
 .Visible = True
End With

Do While ieApp.Busy
    DoEvents
Loop 

Set getStatus = ieApp.Document.getElementById("ProjectStatus_Label1")

strStatus = getStatus.innerText

MsgBox (strStatus) 'gives met the text "Projectstatus, but I need the text "Start"

ieApp.Quit
Set ieApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achieving this, starting from the `ProjectStatus_Label1`, will require some DOM navigation.

Use the following:

```
Do While ieApp.Busy
    DoEvents
Loop
Set labelSpan = ieApp.Document.getElementById("ProjectStatus_Label1")
Set tableHeader = labelSpan.Parent
Set tableRow = tableHeader.Parent
For Each child In tableRow.Children
    If child.tagName = "TD" 'This is the element you're looking for
         Debug.Print child.innerText
         Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Of course, I highly recommend you revise this code and use explicit declarations and `Option Explicit`, but you haven't in your question so I won't in my answer.

Also, I've used a number of assignments (labelSpan, tableHeader) for demonstrative purposes. You can use `Set tableRow = ieApp.Document.getElementById("ProjectStatus_Label1").Parent.Parent` and remove those other declarations.

Or you can use the code-golfy, harder-to-understand approach, starting from the *ProjectStatus* div:

```
Debug.Print ieApp.Document.getElementById("ProjectStatus").GetElementsByTagName("td")(0).innerText
```

Comment: Hi Erik, the code you provided works. I had to change .Parent into .ParentElement. Thanks!

Comment: That's somewhat strange. We must be using a different version of IE (I was working with IE11, and using `ShDocVw.InternetExplorer` with late binding instead of `CreateObject`). It certainly is `.Parent` for me. Documentation on IE automation is sparse, and there's a lot of version incompatibility, so it's mostly trial and error. Glad it worked.